# Vendor Assets Folder only showing .gitkeep rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, stylesheet, asset-pipeline

For some reason, my vendor assets (and lib assets) folders are only showing ".gitkeep" as a file under the stylesheets and javascripts folders.

How can I view the actual files in there?  I know there must be files given all the gems I use, but can't view the stylesheets in there (just showing .gitkeep).  Thank you!

Comment: are you put your asset files into these folder? They are just have ".gitkeep" file when you create new app.

Comment: I have files that i put in app assets but not lib assets or vendor assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's now how rails3 asset pipeline works, Gem assets as per [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#adding-assets-to-your-gems)

> A good example of this is the jquery-rails gem which comes with Rails as the standard JavaScript library gem. This gem contains an engine class which inherits from Rails::Engine. By doing this, **Rails is informed that the directory for this gem may contain assets and the app/assets, lib/assets and vendor/assets directories of this engine are added to the search path of Sprockets**.

Comment: Thanks.  So can I see the files or am I forever blocked from seeing them?

Comment: To add to what @Magicmarkker wrote -- the assets are now in source control under `app/assets`, but they are not actually served from there (in production).  The asset pipeline from Rails 3 gathers these sources from various locations, compiles them (e.g. `.coffee` -> `.js`), fingerprints, and bundles them into a small number of files which are all put in `/public/assets`.  This is done  with `rake assets:precompile` typically as part of deployment.  I fixed the link -- it's an important one.  After reading it 30 times, I came to understand how cool asset pipeline is.

Comment: I want to change one of the files though.  To do that do i just turn precompile off?

Comment: One of the stylesheets from the gem is interfering with my app, and I want to change the stylesheet.  How can I actually see the gem's stylesheet?

Comment: just override whatever styles you want in your own stylesheet in app/assets/stylesheets. There's really no reason to ever touch a gem stylesheet.

Comment: that's not doing it.  I had to go into the public/assets/stylesheets folder as the two were not matching.